# How should make my app backward compatible form android 2.2?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, compatibility

I wrote an application that need to be backward compatible from android 2.2. For that I set up android-support-v7-appcompat and wrote on my AndroidManifest.xml file minsdkVersion is 8. My application contains listView, Fragment, Share Button, Action Bar and showWebPage. I used for fragment and actionBar parts support V7 library and import from this library in my application. I thought with myself it will make my app compatible from version 2.2 but when tried to run my app on htc with android version of 2.2 it installed but didn't lunch after that. My import part look like as follow:

`import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;`

Is there any body have idea why this does happen?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Thank you for answering, but my app run on emulator and I tested it on android 4.3 (My phone). I made decision to release it on google play but I tested on my colleague phone and didn't run. His phone is android 2.2

Comment: Test your app on an Android 2.2 emulator and fix your bugs. Or, test your app on an Android 2.2 device and fix your bugs. Or, raise your `android:minSdkVersion` to a level that you *are* willing to test (e.g., 18, corresponding with Android 4.3). Or, stop distributing this app until such time as you are willing to do one of those things.

Comment: Thank you again, How should I make emulator with android 2.2? When I tried to make new emulator on eclipse i just have one option to select target android 4.3.

Comment: You need to download the emulator images in your SDK Manager.